# Checkboxes vindos da base de dados com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

Tenho uma base de dados com uma tabela chamada `tblapoio`, com 4 campos (`id`, `descricao`, `valor`, `tag`)

Necessitava fazer um formulário com uma lista de *checkboxes* com esses valores que existem na tabela.

Estou a usar CodeIgniter.

Segue uma imagem do que pretendo:
[image: base de dados para checkbox]

Neste momento tenho este *model*:

```
public function apoioPertendido(){      

    $query = $this->db->get('tblapoio');
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            foreach ($query->result() as $rows)) {


            $apoio = array(

                'idapoio' => $rows->idApoio,
                'descricao' => $rows->descricao,
                'valor' => $rows->valor,
                'tag' => $rows->tag,
                );
        }

        return $apoio;
```

RESOLVIDO:

MODEL:

```
 public function apoioPertendido(){     

    $query = $this->db->get('tblapoio');        
    return $query->result(); 


}
```

CONTROLER:

```
public function proporEvento(){

            $natureza = $this->evento_model->naturezaEvento();
            $apoio = $this->evento_model->apoioPertendido();
            $espaco = $this->evento_model->espaco();
            $material = $this->evento_model->material();
            $suportgraf = $this->evento_model->suporteGrafico();
            $audiovisual = $this->evento_model->audioVisual();                  

            $data['title']              = 'Propor Evento';
            $data['naturezaEvento']     = $natureza;
            $data['apoioPertendido']    = $apoio;
            $data['espaco']             = $espaco;
            $data['material']           = $material;
            $data['suporteGraf']        = $suportgraf;
            $data['audioVisual']        = $audiovisual;



            $this->load->view('cliente/clienteheaderdash_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('cliente/clientemenu_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('cliente/clienteproporevento_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('cliente/clientefooterdash_view', $data);
        }
```

VIEW:

```
label>Apoio Pertendido</label>
          <div class="form-group">
                 <?php foreach ($apoioPertendido as $row) { ?>
                 <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="<?php  echo $row->tag ?>" value="<?php   echo $row->idApoio  ?>"/> <?php   echo $row->descricao;  ?>
                   </label>
                   </br>
                <?php }  ?>
          </div>
```

Comment: explica melhor por favor e se voce ja fez alguma parte do codigo tenta postar aqui.

Comment: Poste a resolução na área de respostas, não na própria pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O tipo de apoio pode ser mais de um por chamado? Caso não possa, segue a minha dica, tente usar *radiobuttons* com o mesmo `name`, da seguinte forma:

```
<?php foreach ($apoioPertendido as $row) { ?>
<label>
<input type="radio" class="flat-red" id="apoio" name="apoio" value="<?php   echo $row->idApoio  ?>"/> <?php   echo $row->descricao;  ?>
</label>
</br>
<?php }  ?>
```

Pois desse modo, você não precisará conferir 3 ou 4 vezes (ou de acordo com a quantidade de itens cadastrado no banco), para saber qual o `idApoio`i que está sendo enviado. Para receber o valor no teu *controller* ficaria assim:

```
$tua_variavel = $this->input->post('apoio');
```

Lembrando que, essa solução só servirá se cada chamado ter um tipo de apoio, caso contrário, além de um relacionamento [N para N](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_relacional#Relacionamentos) no banco de dados, você deverá percorrer mais um foreach dentro do controller que receberá os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente vejo que está imprimindo inputs com vários name (**tags diferentes**).
Porém atualmente você ainda tem controle disso, futuramente ao fazer o POST pode ser necessário ler novamente todas tags disponíveis durante o envio por exemplo para saber quais inputs estão na página, isso pode ser solucionado usando um array no seu POST:

Na sua VIEW:

```
<?php foreach ($apoioPertendido as $row) { ?>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="apoio[]" value="<?php   echo $row->idApoio  ?>"/> <?php   echo $row->descricao;  ?>
</label>
</br>
<?php }  ?>
```

**name="apoio[]"**

Dessa forma todos checkboxes marcados com o nome apoio[] serão transformados em um Array com o value de cada um ao fazer o POST.